# Запись в xml-файл

Tags: xml, android

Надо хранить ряд данных в таком виде (в res/xml):

```
<root>
<record date="00.00.00">Text</record>
<record date="00.00.00">Text</record>
</root>
```

Разобрать и вынуть значения могу (XmlPullParser). Но сколько не ищу, не могу найти, где ясно объясняют, как записать в конец новую запись и как удалить или редактировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. res только на чтение, храните просто как файл, с ним и работайте.